# Spray routing - matched path value

Tags: scala, spray, spray-routing

We can use Pipe(|) for path matching in Spray for the use case of "OR" like below.

```
val route =
 path("foo" | "bar" ) {
  complete(??)
}
```

From above example, how to know the value originally it matched (From "foo" or "bar". Which one? ). I didn't find any method giving this.
We can solve this by using a Map and it gives the value. Without using "Map", can i get matched string.

```
val route =
  path(Map("foo"->"foo", "bar"->"bar" )) { mathcedString => 
   complete(matchedString)
  }
}
```

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/path-directives/path/

Comment: If you need to know which one matched you need two different endpoints, the or makes it implicit that you don't care which one of the two you just matched.

Comment: Hmm.. Can't we do any thing with regex? Thinking of implementing a Set using regex and get output?